# Is it possible to refresh/reset IBOutlet as its designed in IB?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, reset, iboutlet

Let's say, in my code, I have adjusted many many IBOutlet (like, frame, border, color, text, etc...), depend on user interaction. Then when things get so messed up, I'd like to let user reset all of them to its base designed from interface-builder (storyboard, xib, nib).

Is it possible to write a few code to reset all subviews (or IBOutlet, as both are fine) in one partical view or I'll have to rewrite everything? (Note that I just want to reset a view's subviews, not the whole view itself).

Comment: have you tried to `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` ???

Comment: @VarunNaharia Sorry for this late response, I haven't online for a while. And yes, I've tried `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutSubviews`. It does not reset my subview :(

Comment: then try to recreate the UIViewController

Comment: recreate the whole ViewController? I just want to reset a tiny little part of it, not the whole thing itself :/

Comment: Hmm.. you mean it can't do automatically, but have to tell everything all by yourself **again**?

Comment: it's hard to help without access to code if you'll provide a demo appliction then I can help you by giving exact solution